# Can a neural network be configured to output a matrix in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I am working with predicting a time series in 3 dimensions and would like to know if it is possible to configure a model to output a martix in Keras.

Currently, I have 3 regression models I train one after the other, one for predicting each output dimension. With a prediction horizon of 10 samples for example, each model is outputting a 10x1 vector. However, it seems like this could be done much more efficiently with a single model.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I have found a much better way to do this using the Keras core layer Reshape. For a prediction horizon by predicted variables sized output, add a Reshape layer after the dense layer with that shape

```
from keras.layers import Dense, Reshape, Sequential, LSTM

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100, activation='relu', return_sequences=True, input_shape=(n_steps_in, n_features)))
model.add(LSTM(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(n_steps_out*n_features))
model.add(Reshape((n_steps_out,n_features)))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a pretty easy work around. I just reshape the targets on the way in and reshape the predictions on the way out.

```
    input_data = input_data.reshape((num_simulations,input_samples*3))
    target_data = target_data.reshape((num_simulations,horizon*3))

    model.fit(input_data, target_data, validation_split=0.2, epochs=epochs, 
            batch_size=batch_size, verbose=0, shuffle=True)

    prediction = model.predict(input_data, batch_size=batch_size)
    prediction = prediction.reshape((num_simulations,horizon,3))
```